# Updating Imagemagick on Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, imagemagick, heic

On a project I'm working on, I need to update Imagemagick to at least 7.0.8, in order to have support for HEIC  I'm uncertain how to do that, though.

In my composer.json file, I have this:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework":    "4.2.x-dev",
    "intervention/image": "dev-master",
    --- rest of composer.json ---
```

---

According to `phpinfo()`, that gets me ImageMagick 6.7.7-10.

I'm uncertain how to proceed to update ImageMagick (both locally, and eventually to the production environment) to the version I need.

I guess, first I need to ask, is this even possible under Laravel 4? (If it's not, then the rest of this becomes a moot point, because the project scope doesn't allow for the time to update the entire project to Laravel 5.)

If it is possible, what am I missing? Is there a simple package I can add?

Edit: This project is using PHP 5.6

Comment: Even if you can install IM 7, you still need to install the libheic delegate and everything it needs before installing ImageMagick. See https://medium.com/@eplt/5-minutes-to-install-imagemagick-with-heic-support-on-ubuntu-18-04-digitalocean-fe2d09dcef1

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier, had a whole bunch of stuff come up at work.

Does that require PHP 7.2? The second step seems to say that it does.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer to that question about PHP. I do not see why it would depend upon PHP. It might depend upon Imagick version with uses ImageMagick.